# Create and build pure "ActionScript project" with Flex SDK under Linux

Tags: linux, actionscript, apache-flex

Before all: excuse my english :)

Ok, here we go - im developing mostly java things, so my IDE - Intellij IDEA.
For a few last weeks im playing with Flex and AS3. So, im using Flex SDK 3 with IDEA plugin.

Everything was just fine, but now i want to create pure actionscript project without any flex things (it dramatically increases size of final swf).

I can understand that I have to play with flex-config and such things, but Im new to Flex and flash techs at all, so I have no clue what to do.

Googling didnt help me much with it, all things explains what to do in Flex Builder.

So, I'd love if someone would tell me - what exactly i have to do to compile pure actionscript project with pure Flex SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mxmlc DocumentClass.as`

Comment: Errr... 
Thanx for pointing :) 

My problem was that IDEA is loading some strange config for compiler.
Now all look just fine.

One more time thank you for 'shocking' me :)